# Query Failed Error: Property had unexpected type. Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have an external table linked to our GCS account in Google BigQuery. I am attempting to run a simple SELECT query (select * from [.] LIMIT 10) with Google BigQuery Web UI. The table has around 13 GB of data. The scheme looks as if it is able to see the data correctly.

The error I received is as such:

> **Query Failed**
>
> **Error:** Property had unexpected type.
>
> **Job ID:** csgapi:bquijob_3e7a58f7_155e4baea88

Comment: I also receive the same error when attempting to import the GCS backup file as a native table. (Job ID: csgapi:bquijob_12fb990f_155e4d122f4)

Comment: We investigated internally. Some types of properties in datastorebackup files shouldn't have the "meanings" field set. There's a property in your file that has such a type but has the "meanings" field set. The error message does need to be improved to expose the name of the property. We filed a bug internally to track it.

Comment: @HuaZhang I have researched this more. We have a few properties within our model that leverage `ndb.DateTimeProperty`. Within this class, specifically the `google.appengine.ext.ndb.model.DateTimeProperty` class, the method for _db_set_value NDB performs a `p.set_meaning` upon the property. Thus all entities that contain these properties have the "meanings" field set to the type. Any help would be great how to remedy this issue. We have a lot of data that leverages this model.

See ndb class here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model

Comment: Is it correct to say this issue is solved?

Comment: Not as of yet. My properties that have a meaning field value are all NDB data structures that have the meaning fields set by the system. I have imported these date time properties before without issues. @HuaZhang are you able to post what specifically is breaking it?

Comment: Apparently the issue spawned internally to track this problem is marked as fixed. It could then be a matter of updating your SDK and redeploying the code. Let me know if you're still seeing it after that.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I will test this today.

Comment: This seems to be fixed with proper error messaging. "Result: query: Property established_year of type integer has meaning INDEX_VALUE, but is not expected to have any meaning. (error code: invalidQuery)."  Any help on why I am getting this error would be great.

Comment: See this post for resolution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215721/property-has-meaning-index-value-but-is-not-expected-to-have-any-meaning

Comment: @Nick this can be closed