# Property has meaning INDEX_VALUE, but is not expected to have any meaning

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am receiving an error from BigQuery when attempting to load data from a cloud backup.


From Google BigQuery Console

> **Errors**:
>   query: Property established_year of type integer has meaning INDEX_VALUE, but is not expected to have any meaning. (error code: invalidQuery)
>
> **Job ID**:    csgapi:bquijob_736ab47b_156b2f2a4f8

I have looked up in the model that the error is referencing to and it is of type ndb.IntegerProperty. When I then look at the Property class that ndb.IntegerProperty extends, I see a comment where `new_p.set_meaning(entity_pb.Property.INDEX_VALUE)` is set ([Docs here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model)) that says.

```
# Projected properties have the INDEX_VALUE meaning and only contain
# the original property's name and value.
```

How is my property of type ndb.IntegerProperty have this INDEX_VALUE set and what must I do to fix this?

**EDIT**

Looking further into this, I was curious as to why the property was even being included on this item. According to the model I have two elements that could be the offending properties. The first property is company, which is an NDB.KeyProperty, which does not seem likely because this would only create a reference. The other is a Generic Property, company_base, that is not indexed and also is mapped on query; this is not saved to the data store. We have 14 GB of data for this specific kind. I have attempted to loop through all the elements within the backup to search for the field company_base, but I am not able to find the elements that are in the file.

I have looked at other kinds that use this same structure, and their schema's do not appear to have the same "company_base" within their schema. They too should not save that element to the datastore.

**If the elements are appearing in the backup schema, does that mean that at some point in time these non-indexed properties were saved to the datastore and thus appear in the backup?**

The generic field "company_base" from the backup schema:

```
field {
  name: "company_base"
  type {
    is_list: false
    embedded_schema {
      kind: "Company"
      field {
        name: "ambest_outlook"
        type {
          is_list: false
          primitive_type: STRING
        }
      }
      field {
        name: "name_full"
        type {
          is_list: false
          primitive_type: STRING
        }
      }
      field {
        name: "established_year"
        type {
          is_list: false
          primitive_type: INTEGER
        }
      }
      field {
        name: "ambest_rating"
        type {
          is_list: false
          primitive_type: STRING
        }
      }
      field {
        name: "parent_company"
        type {
          is_list: false
          primitive_type: REFERENCE
        }
      }
      field {
        name: "sp_rating"
        type {
          is_list: false
          primitive_type: STRING
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Smitty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the schema, though it would only appear on the entire backup, there appeared a single element with wrong type. The wouldn't appear normally due to NDB's structure. The only way that I was able to fix this issue was to navigate the entities and remove the offending properties to ensure correctness.

It took a long time for the system to fix it via iteration, but they were not searchable items.